# Why does org-mode not indent content under headings when I press tab?

Tags: org-mode, indentation

In a buffer like this:

```
* Heading
** Sub-heading
content|
```

pressing `<tab>` should result in this:

```
* Heading
** Sub-heading
   content|
```

Instead, nothing happens.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Org's indentation behaviour is controlled by the `org-adapt-indentation` variable. It can be set to three states:

`t`: Adapt indentation for all lines
`headline-data`: Adapt indentation for headline data lines
`nil`: Do not adapt indentation at all

If you want org-mode to indent heading content, do `(setq org-adapt-indentation t)`.