# Org mode recursive section indentation

Tags: org-mode, indentation

I would like to add a "super-heading" with recursive section indentation.

By that I mean that I want to transform the content:

```
* Fruits
** Durian
** Jackfruit
** Lychee
```

to become

```
* Produce
** Fruits
*** Durian
*** Jackfruit
*** Lychee
```

But of course whatever is under "Durian" etc also need to be appropriately indented.

Is there a way to do this?

##### Related

- [Why does org-mode not indent content under headings when I press tab?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/70228/28733)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can demote the whole `Fruits` subtree with `M-S-<right>` (hold down `Meta` and `Shift` and press the right arrow). That key combo is bound to the function `org-shiftmetaright` which does context-dependent things: when it is at a heading it calls `org-demote-subtree` which does what you want with the `Fruits` subtree.

The doc string of `org-shiftmetaright` which you can get with `C-h f org-shiftmetaright` says:

```
Demote subtree or insert table column.
Calls ‘org-demote-subtree’, ‘org-indent-item-tree’, or
‘org-table-insert-column’, depending on context.  See the
individual commands for more information.
```

You can then add a top-level `Produce` heading by opening up an empty line above with `C-O`, if necessary, and adding a heading with `M-RET`.

Demoting a subtree can also be done through the `Org` menu item,: look under `Edit Structure/Demote subtree`. See [Structure Editing](https://orgmode.org/manual/Structure-Editing.html) in the Org manual for more structure-editing commands.